# Django admin select ordering different than default model ordering

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have a model (Node) which is ordered by date in the admin, so latest nodes are shown first. This is fine.

The same model (Node) is referenced by another model (Device). When editing a device there is a list of nodes (in an HTML select) which is also ordered by date.
I would like this select to be ordered by name and not by date.

Is it possible to have two different ordering methods, one for the list of objects and one for the select box?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest thing would be to override the [`formfield_for_foreignkey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey) method in the `ModelAdmin` for `Device`, something like

```
def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
    if db_field.name == 'node':
        kwargs['queryset'] = Node.objects.order_by('name')
    return super(DeviceAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

(I'm assuming a fair amount here. Hopefully it's clear!)

Similarly there's `formfield_for_manytomany`.

Comment: thanks, it works as you can see here: https://github.com/ninuxorg/nodeshot/issues/65

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried something like:

```
class Node
        name = ...
        date = ...
        fields ....

        class Meta:
            order_with_respect_to='Device'
            ordering = ('Device', 'name')
```

Comment: i didn't know that option, +1 for teaching me something new, but i don't think it solves my problem

Comment: This solution would still need something like whats mentioned in the accepting answer to get <select>'s in the admin panel to list the values in proper hierarchy. Instead of a ``order_by()``, i think you'd use ``get_MODELNAME_order()`` as explained here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#order-with-respect-to

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom form for DeviceAdmin and set queryset parameter for 'Node' field.

```
# in models.py we have Device model with Node field
class Device(models.Model):
    node = models.ForeignKey(Node)
    ...

# in admin.py we have DeviceAdmin with custom form
class DeviceAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    node = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Node.objects.order_by('name'), label='Node')

    class Meta:
        model = Device

class DeviceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = DeviceAdminForm
```